# What is the error in the following mysql statement?

Tags: mysql

```
"INSERT INTO messages (idR,idS,nameS,message,read) VALUES     ($id,'$_SESSION[id]','$myname','$message',1)";
```

It says you have mysql error syntax near'read) VALUES ($id,'$_SESSION[id]','$myname','$message',1)'

Comment: Hi Mehman, and welcome to Stack Overflow! You'll find people more likely to help if you format your code to make it a little more easy to read; if you respond to requests to add code or examples to your *question* rather than in comments; and if you place a tick in answers that are correct. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 2):

The word `read` is a reserved word.  Put it in backquotes:

```
INSERT INTO messages (idR, idS, nameS, message, `read`)
    VALUES ($id, '$_SESSION[id]', '$myname', '$message', 1)
```

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) is the list of MySQL reserved words.